# Fool-proofing a JSON load

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I have a function in a program that loads JSON files from the local directory, However I'm trying to make this function a little more "fool-proof" in case one of the JSON files is missing (I tried on purpose and it crashes if it doesn't find the JSON). I wanted to know if its possible to do something like:
"If it's not in the local directory, download it from X-web directory or if offline just omit it"
Here's what my Code looks like as of now:

```
func loadStash{
        for var sourceFile in STASHES_SELECTED
        {
         let stashUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sourceFile, withExtension: "JSON")
            do {
                let json = try? Data(contentsOf: stashUrl!)

                let stashLoad = try JSONDecoder().decode([StashStyle].self, from: json!)
                loadedStashes += stashLoad


            } catch {
                print("**THERE WAS AN ERROR!!**")
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE: loadedStashes is an array of Structures (StashStyle)  and it gets bigger and bigger the more stashes are loaded (successfully) into it.
STASHES_SELECTED is an array of strings with the file-names of each JSON file

Comment: Just use optional binding in the line to get the URL. And remove the question mark after `try`.  By the way why is `sourceFile` a variable?

Comment: I assumed sourceFile is a variable since it changes on each iteration of the for loop doesn't it?. How would optional binding work on that line? is it let stashUrl? or is it Bundle?.main.url... or is it forResource: sourceFile?

Comment: `if let stashUrl = Bundle.main...`